# How to get Date_Difference MONTHS , DAYS in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Now i want to display months and days between two dates e.g:-

```
start_date       end_date
---------        -------- 
1-10-2020        2-11-2020

expected output 
----------------
MONTH       DAYS 
10          30
11          2
```

How to get it in oracle ???

Comment: This is very difficult to define accurately because months have different numbers of days.  You can get months difference as a decimal number, but converting to days is a bit fraught.  What is the difference between Jan 31 and Feb 28, for instance?

Comment: i know but i want to display the month , num of days per month ,

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The "expected output" shows what the OP really wants: he wants to show all the calendar months that have an overlap with the interval given, and then for each of those months, the extent of the overlap (in number of days). The question title is misleading - you are right that THAT would have been a hard problem, but that's not what this poster is really asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a calendar (between start and end date), extract month (and year, for situations where those dates span several years) and count number of days in those months.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (start_date, end_date) as
  3    (select date '2020-10-01',
  4            date '2020-11-02'
  5     from dual
  6    ),
  7  calendar as
  8    (select start_date + level - 1 datum
  9     from test
 10     connect by level <= end_date - start_date + 1
 11    )
 12  select to_char(datum, 'yyyy.mm') month,
 13         count(*) days
 14  From calendar
 15  group by to_char(datum, 'yyyy.mm')
 16  order by 1;

MONTH         DAYS
------- ----------
2020.10         31
2020.11          2

SQL>
```

(By the way, October has 31 days, not 30).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate all the days as it'll be inefficient; just use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to iterate over each month:

```sql
WITH months ( start_date, next_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT start_date,
         LEAST(
           ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' ), 1 ),
           CAST( end_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY AS DATE )
         ),
         CAST( end_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY AS DATE )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT next_date,
         LEAST( ADD_MONTHS( next_date, 1 ), end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   months
  WHERE  next_date < end_date
)
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM start_date ) AS year,
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM start_date ) AS month,
       next_date - start_date AS days
FROM   months;
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_date, end_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-10-01', DATE '2020-11-02' FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> YEAR | MONTH | DAYS
> ---: | ----: | ---:
> 2020 |    10 |   31
> 2020 |    11 |    2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=09481b887eb89cc9f312b23df61c2523)*

Answer (score 1):

Rather then internally listing every day, you could get all of the (partial) months involved, and then see how many days in each of those is in-range:

```
with cte (start_date, end_date) as (
  select date '2020-10-01', date '2020-11-02' from dual
),
rcte (start_date, end_date, part_month) as (
  select start_date, end_date, trunc(start_date, 'MM')
  from cte
  union all
  select start_date, end_date, part_month + interval '1' month
  from rcte
  where part_month < trunc(end_date, 'MM')
)
select extract(month from part_month) as month_num,
  least(end_date, last_day(part_month))
    - greatest(start_date, part_month)
    + 1 as num_days
from rcte
order by part_month;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ee2aba833b5ef955766b011542a3cfd) showing some of the working.